# Почему getUint8, getUint16 и getUint32 дают разные значения. Как из 255 получается 65535 или 4294967295? Что происходит за кулисами?

Tags: javascript, buffer

```
var buffer = new Uint8Array([255,255,255,255]).buffer;
let data_view = new DataView(buffer);
console.log(data_view.getUint8(0));     // Вернёт 255.
console.log(data_view.getUint16(0));    // Вернёт 65535.
console.log(data_view.getUint32(0));    // Вернёт 4294967295.
```

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

Я кажется понял. На эти все четыре числа Uint8Array([255,255,255,255]) буфер только один. То есть вбив 255 четыре раза, мы сразу создали 32-х битное пространство буфера заполненное единицами. То есть мы получается создали буфер 11111111111111111111111111111111. Так как каждое число 255 это 11111111 (восемь единичек), а четыре раза по 255 это 32 единички. Вот буфер и заполнился единичками. А методами .getUint8(0), .getUint16(0) и .getUint32(0) мы выбираем сколько бит нам надо начиная с левой стороны.

Так например если мы создадим представление буфера только из трёх чисел по 255, и попробуем получить результат методом .getUint32(0), то интерпретатор вернёт нам ошибку. Так как в буфере всего 3 числа * 8 бит каждое число = 24 бита, и так как 255 это максимальное 8-ми битное значение, то мы получаем 24 единички. А методу .getUint32(0) нужно чтобы бит было 32, но у нас всего бит 24, поэтому мы видим ошибку.

```
var buffer = new Uint8Array([255,255,255]).buffer;
let data_view = new DataView(buffer);
console.log(data_view.getUint32(0));    // Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
```

Comment: Молодец.  *(нужно ещё 6 символов...)*

Answer (score -2):

8 бит в двоичной системе счисления 11111111 = 255 десятичных.
Соответственно возвращаются данные для 16 и 32 бит.

Comment: ну так а почему данные дополняются единицами, а не нулями, что более логично

Comment: Потому что заполняется старшим битом, а не нулем